# Yum doesn't list a package I'd like, now what?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I'm Linux ignorant. We're using CentOS and I have a need to install something called `git-up` and I understand that package managers are how you install everything onto Linux. CentOS has `yum` but the package I want is not coming back in searches.

What do I do now? I assume it has some kind of package source registry, but can I connect to any? Where are they? How do I find one that has what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git-up is a ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/git-up), not a yum package.

Install it by issuing this command `gem install git-up`

Comment: `gem` is not installed (command not found) so I have to `yum install gem` first?

Comment: @LukePuplett - Should be installed when ruby is installed. Ruby should be in your yum repository.

Comment: Okay lots of ruby stuff on the screen, is there a website for yum? I'm a VS.NET dev, we have NuGet package manager, we visit a site to research the right package get its ID, then we return to the CLI to install it.

Comment: @LukePuplett -  Read: http://www.bonusbits.com/main/HowTo:Install_Ruby_on_CentOS If you get stuck ask a new question with your problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It's getting exhausting, I might just code what I need and run it on a Windows VM.

Answer (score 1):

Please try searching the package using the below command

To search for a specific package by name

```
su -c 'yum list git'
```

To search for all packages that include files called git

```
su -c 'yum provides git'
```

To list all packages with names that begin with tsc

```
su -c 'yum list git\*'
```

Also I checked in Google and got the link that explains that EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository will be need to install git. For further details refer the link below

[setting-up-git-on-centos-5-server/](http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2010/01/29/setting-up-git-on-centos-5-server/)

Comment: Thanks, I think (its hard when I don't know what I'm talking about) Nifle is on the right track, since git is installed, I need this little helper widget thing.